# Multiple Inserted Row Ids

Tags: mysql, sql

I am inserting multiple rows at once like:

```
INSERT INTO person VALUES ('joe', 50), ('jon', 24);
```

I then need to use their id to link the above to another table. Normally I would do that by using `LAST_INSERT_ID()`

```
INSERT INTO hobbies VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), "golf");
```

but that's not viable with inserting multiple values as `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns the id of the first inserted row.

I could just increment `LAST_INSERT_ID()` after each hobby insertion but that assumes that all people rows were inserted successfully.

The other option is to just insert the people rows one at a time but I don't know whether that's a performance hit?

Comment: Just use multiple statements and insert each person separately. As long as they are within the *same transaction* the performance should be similar.

Comment: LAST_INSERT_ID() returns the insert id of one record. cant be used with multiple records insertion!

Comment: You can use triggers to insert row on each new entry to table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the values using single statements and wrap them into a transaction, e.g:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO person  VALUES ('joe', 50);
INSERT INTO hobbies VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'golf');
COMMIT;
```

You may take a slight performance hit but this should give you consistent results. Incrementing the value returned by `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is not safe as there may have been concurrent inserts that modified the `AUTO INCREMENT` value.

Comment: It's not ideal but you could lock the table and then you'd be sure that you could get a range of auto_increment values